# Drupal 7, ubercart product node breadcrumbs

Tags: drupal-7, breadcrumbs, drupal-taxonomy

I'm creating an Ubercart 3 webshop in Drupal 7. Everything works but there is one thing I can't figure out.

The breadcrumb on the product node looks like:

Shopname -> Product

The breadcrumb I would like is with my taxonomy categories like:

Shopname -> taxonomy -> term -> Product

My Drupal version is Drupal 7

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

For providing a breadcrumb drupal uses main menu.

Right now your "Product doesn't have any "parent". That menu item is in the same level as Home/Shopname.

So, to have a breadcrumb like "Shopname -> taxonomy -> term -> Product" you have to set parent(s) items for your product.

Answer (score 0):

I have also gone from problem like this.I have set up taxonomy path for my site where the
i have used default taxonomy views.

In your case i guess "Product" is your content type& you entered data using taxonomy & you want those vocabulary display here with term you referenced.

I am suggesting to use drupal module "Custom Breadcrumbs". You can set path using this modules views portion.
If you have view for menu (here i guess 'shopname').Select your views path.Place your referenced field in title & path using token given there & save.

In configuration settings check first & third option to place hierarchy of taxonomy in your path.& other settings for taxonomy as your need.

Hope this could work..
Thanks